# handling null values in text box in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, scriptlet

Say a text box takes value from Transfer Object as below in a jsp:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="test" ID="test" value="<%=testTO.getTest()%>">
```

However, if getTest returns null, null will be displayed.

How to use ? :  with scriptlet so that if the value is null, blank is displayed else the value returned from TO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it like this for printing blank:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="test" ID="test" value="<%= ((testTO.getTest()==null)?"":testTO.getTest()) %>">
```

ok add this condition

```
(&& testTO.getTest().length() == 0)
```

if it is already returning a String if not you must use this

```
(&& testTO.getTest().toString().length() == 0)
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="test" ID="test" value="<%= ((testTO.getTest()==null && testTO.getTest().length() == 0)?"":testTO.getTest()) %>">
```

Comment: this solution is not working... value="<%=(testTO.getSomeDt()==null)?'':dateFormat.format(testTO.getLastPriceDt())%>"  is throwing error at ' ' as invalid character..

Answer (score 3):

```
testTO.getTest() == null ? "" : testTO.getTest()
```

try this , it will surely work.

Answer (score 2):

If your're using WebLogic Server, there's a setting (see [Using the WebLogic JSP Compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jsp/reference.html#65756))

```
-noPrintNulls

Shows "null" in jsp expressions as "".
```

which prevents the `null` in this case. **Your container may have a similar feature.** Advantage: no code change required. I think this can also be set in weblogic.xml.

Answer (score 1):

To hide null spaces in JSP :-

I am not sure will it help you or not but it worked well in my case.

I am using web-logic 10.3 and the jsp in which I want to hide nulls is part of my web application.

Steps:

1. Find Weblogic.xml in your Package Explorer.
2. open this Weblogic.xml.
3. Click on JSP Tab of the Weblogic.xml.
4. On the JSP tab under Output Options(Top Right) unchecked the "Print Nulls" check box.
5. Build and deploy the application no Null will be displayed in the text box any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(testTO.getTest()!=null) {    
out.print("<input type=\"text\" name=\"test\" id=\"test\" value=\""+testTO.getTest()+"\">");}
else
{
out.print("<input type=\"text\" name=\"test\" id=\"test\" value=\"\">");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? He is not asking about using **if** just asking about **?:** --the conditional operators.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EL` or `JSTL` expression. The Expression language is [null safe](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).